# C++ How to check if letter isalpha (not latin alphabet)

Tags: c++, string, character-encoding

so I need to see if my character is a letter. I tried using isalpha() function, however, if I try to pass not latin letter (for example ą, č, ę, ė, į, š, ų, ū, ž) I get an error, that seems to state that isalpha function accepts only chars that in ASCII code are between 0 and 255. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [locale version of `std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha). Taking an example from the linked reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    const wchar_t c = L'\u042f'; // cyrillic capital letter ya

    std::locale loc1("C");
    std::cout << "isalpha('Я​', C locale) returned "
               << std::boolalpha << std::isalpha(c, loc1) << '\n';

    std::locale loc2("en_US.UTF8");
    std::cout << "isalpha('Я', Unicode locale) returned "
              << std::boolalpha << std::isalpha(c, loc2) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
isalpha('Я​', C locale) returned false
isalpha('Я', Unicode locale) returned true
```

Comment: @MohitBhasi: Copy/pasted the code, actually. Like I said, it's from the linked page.